# ASP.NET Core set custom DependencyInjection service lifecycle

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, lifetime

According to the Dependency injection in .NET documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes

In ASP.NET Core, there are three DependencyInjection service lifecycles:

Transient, Scoped, and Singleton.

I need the class to live as a Singleton, but so that when accessing the domain from another computer or from the same computer, but in a new browser window (For example, New Incognito Windows), a new instance of the class is created.

Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: For what you described above Scoped will be the best

Comment: a scoped lifetime indicates that services are created once per client request (connection), I don' think  Singleton can fit your requirement. It will only create once during the whole project lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a singleton, you need a scoped. Singleton is shared within the app instance. there is ONE per running instance. Multiple requests like when you call an api method all get that same singleton. if you want one instance of a service that lives during the lifetime of your request you need a scoped service. if within that request you want a new service every time you use it you need the transient.

Comment: I'm using builder.Services.AddSingleton to setup class for application State.
But AddScoped destroys the State when the user clicks the Refresh page.
I want the state to stay on Refresh.

Comment: State is a whole different topic. In general using session state (state saved on the backend per user during his session) is discouraged. One reason for that is that is does not scale well, multiple instances of your webapp would need a shared state store or you would need to force sticky sessions. A singleton service to keep sessionstate for all your users has that same problem, and you would be reinventing session state. For what data do you need sessions state?

Comment: I have a multipage input form.
At the end of the input, the data is sent to the mail.
I store the entered data and the page number in a special EditFormParameter class that I register via
builder.Services.AddScoped<EditFormParameter>();
If the user clicks “Refresh” on one of the pages, then all the data is reset and he has to enter the data again.
The customer does not accept this form of input.

Comment: you could store that state on the browser/c;ient using localstorage or cookies. that is still available after refresh.